# Proposed change comments don’t automatically update

Tags: feature-request, bug, documentation, comments, proposed-changes

On Q&A, if new comments are posted, a link appears:

[image: show **9** more comments]

However, on Documentation, you have to reload to see new comments.

It would be great if new comments were AJAXed in.